# How to get array list values to listpicker in windwos phone?

Tags: c#, arrays, xaml, windows-phone, listpicker

Hi i am developing windows phone app. i need to get array list values and display list picker.i am facing problem is i got array value from list but in that list shows single values for all elements.i am given below images and code. please anyone help me how resolve in this issue.

My code is given below

```
<toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="RetailerList" ItemsSource="{Binding Producttype}"  Foreground="Black" BorderThickness="0"  Margin="30,-1,10,0" SelectionChanged="listPicker_SelectionChanged" >
                                    <toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding retailer_namestring}" FontSize="20" FontFamily="Arial"  Foreground="Black"  TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
                                    <toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding retailer_namestring}" FontSize="20" FontFamily="Arial"  Foreground="Black"  TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
                                </toolkit:ListPicker>
```

```
List<Members> test = new List<Members>();
foreach (var d in myMember.retailer_name)
{
    test.Add(new Members { retailer_namestring = myMember.retailer_name[0].ToString() });
}

this.RetailerList.ItemsSource =test;
```

I got result given below image

[image]

I need output like

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your forloop, d is not used and retailer_namestring is always set to the same string fixed myMember.retailer_name[0].

Answer (score 0):

Supossing that myMember.retailer_name is the array, you are fetching the same element, `myMember.retailer_name[0]`,  in each loop, instead of using the element you have in variable `d` in each loop. Try the following:

```
 foreach (var d in myMember.retailer_name)
 {
     test.Add(new Members { retailer_namestring = d.ToString() });
 }
```